# angular4 html template iteration and ngIf directive

Tags: angular, comparison, angular2-directives

I am binding an array of objects to my html template using the ngFor structural directive like this:

```
<div *ngFor=let g of groupsList">
```

Each group referenced by g contains a property called type.  The elements in groupsList are already sorted by type.  Meaning objects in elements 0-10 should have TypeA, elements in 11-35 are TypeB, etc.  However the number of total objects and objects of each type are dynamic.

I need to compare type of each object to the object that came before it and display or not display a different div within the one shown above dependent upon if those two values differ.

Iteration of groupsList occurs in the template due to the ngFor directive.  As such I assume that I have to do this comparison there in the template as well rather than in my component.

Is the right way of doing this to create a couple ng-containers and do two way binding to two variables in my component named something like priorType and currentType?

**Updated with short solution**:

```
<div *ngFor="let g of groupsList; let i=index">
<div *ngIf="(i==0) || (i>0 && g.type != groupsList[i-1].type)">
```

Comment: "compare type of each object to the object that came before", by that you mean the one immediately before g[index -1], or all the ones that are before current object?

Comment: @Nehal just the one the came immediately before it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's sample html where you can compare an object with it's previous object and show different `div` based on the comparison.

```
<div *ngFor="let g of groupsList; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i == 0">
      {{ g | json }}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="i > 0 ">
      {{ g | json }}
      <h4 *ngIf="(groupsList[i].type != groupsList[i-1].type)" style="background: green">Type doesn't match with previous</h4>
      <h4 *ngIf="(groupsList[i].type == groupsList[i-1].type)" style="background: red">Type matches with previous</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/BvJyP3eExBw7rCB3UBCm)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I happened to figure the solution out on my own and was about to post the answer when you replied with yours.  Ive marked yours as correct as it represents the same.